# How to simplify big conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have five dropdowns, and I need to put conditions on each of them. My code is:

```
   def search(search, compare, year, rain_fall_type)
    if search == 'All'
      if rain_fall_type == 'All'
        all
      else
        if year == 'All'
          if rain_fall_type == "None"
            where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id')
          else
            # all
             where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order('id')
          end
        else
          if rain_fall_type == "All"
            order("#{year} ")

          elsif rain_fall_type == "None"
            where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id')
           else
            where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order("#{year} ")
           end
        end
        # where(Year: year).order("#{rain_fall_type} ")
      end
    elsif compare != "None"
      if year == 'All'
        where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', rain_fall_type, compare).order(:id)
      else
        where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', rain_fall_type, compare).order(:id)
      end
    else

      if rain_fall_type == 'All'
        all.order('id')
      else
        if year == 'All'

          if rain_fall_type == "None"
            where('Sector = ? ', search).order('id')
          else

            where('Sector = ? ', rain_fall_type).order('id')
          end
        else

          if rain_fall_type == "None"

            if search == "All"
              where('Sector = ? ', search).order('id')
            else
              where('Sector = ? ', search).order('id')
            end
          else
            # all
            where('Sector = ? ', rain_fall_type).order('id')
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

It has many `if` and `else`. I am trying to minimise the conditions. What can be the best way to shrink this code? Someone suggested that I should use `switch` `case` instead. Should I use it? If so, how?

Comment: Is this an actual code in one of your application or are you just asking us to help in refactoring ? The reason I'm asking is, there seems to be a redundant lines.

Comment: This is actual code I am using.

Comment: @Verty00 you can put anything in the variables.

Comment: I understand that. I need to see where you call this. And how you get the values. For instance are you loading params into this method in the conroller?

Comment: I am getting params and passing it to search function in model. I am using module and I am extending it into my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, some of your logic doesn't make sense:

```
def search(search, compare, year, rain_fall_type)
  if search == 'All'
    if rain_fall_type == 'All'
      all
    else
      # rain_fall_type != 'All'
      if year == 'All'
        if rain_fall_type == "None"
          where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id')
        else
          where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order('id')
        end
      else
        # in rain_fall_type != 'All' branch, so meaningless 'if'
        if rain_fall_type == "All"
          order("#{year} ")
        elsif rain_fall_type == "None"
          where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id')
        else
          where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order("#{year} ")
        end
      end
    end
  elsif compare != "None"
    # both are same, so meaningless 'if'
    if year == 'All'
      where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', rain_fall_type, compare).order(:id)
    else
      where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', rain_fall_type, compare).order(:id)
    end
  else
    # search != 'All'
    if rain_fall_type == 'All'
      all.order('id')
    else
      if year == 'All'
        if rain_fall_type == "None"
          where('Sector = ? ', search).order('id')
        else
          where('Sector = ? ', rain_fall_type).order('id')
        end
      else
        if rain_fall_type == "None"
          # in search != 'All' branch, so meaningless 'if'
          # AND both are same, so again meaningless 'if'
          if search == "All"
            where('Sector = ? ', search).order('id')
          else
            where('Sector = ? ', search).order('id')
          end
        else
          where('Sector = ? ', rain_fall_type).order('id')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There's more like that and I won't point it all out because we're throwing all that `if` stuff out, anyway.

Ultimately, we're going to defer the querying to the end of the method, like this:

```
def search(search, compare, year, rain_fall_type)

  ...

  @query = all 
  @query = @query.where(Sector: @sectors) if @sectors
  @query = @query.order(@order) if @order
  @query

end
```

That way, you take *all* of your `where` and `order` statements, and do them only once at the end. That saves a lot of typing right there. See the comment from muistooshort for why `(Sector: @sectors)` works.

So, the trick is setting `@sectors` and `@order`.  First, I'm going to assign the input variables to instance variables because I like it like that (and to avoid confusion between the variable `@search` and the method `search`):

```
def search(search, compare, year, rain_fall_type)
  @search, @compare, @year, @rain_fall_type = search, compare, year, rain_fall_type

  ...

  @query = all 
  @query = @query.where(Sector: @sectors) if @sectors
  @query = @query.order(@order) if @order
  @query
end
```

Now, this answer is going on too long already, so I won't drag you through all the gorey details. But, adding in a couple of helper methods (`sectors_to_use`, and `order_to_use`) and substituting them in for `@sectors` and `@order`, you basically end up with this:

```
def search(search, compare, year, rain_fall_type)
  @search, @compare, @year, @rain_fall_type = search, compare, year, rain_fall_type
  @query = all 
  @query = @query.where(Sector: sectors_to_use) if sectors_to_use
  @query = @query.order(order_to_use) if order_to_use
  @query
end

private 

def sectors_to_use
  return [@rain_fall_type, @compare] if @search != 'All' && @compare != 'None'
  unless @rain_fall_type == 'All'
    if @rain_fall_type == 'None'
      @search == 'All' ? ['Primary', 'Secondary', 'Tertiary'] : [@search]
    else
      [@rain_fall_type]
    end  
  end
end

def order_to_use
  return nil if (@search == 'All') && (@rain_fall_type == 'All')
  return @year if (@search == 'All') && !(@year == 'All')
  return :id
end
```

That's less than half the lines of code, over a thousand fewer characters, and a whole lot fewer `ifs`.

Comment: Thanks for answering the perfect answer, If you can explain that would be great and where I was doing wrong.

Comment: Some of the logic is working but compare!= "none" not working.

Comment: Hang on. Found a bug and fixing it. I'll look at that, too.

Comment: I think that fixed it and my RSPEC tests seem to be passing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a guard statement which is basically `return something if some_condition?`. This only doable in specific scenarios (where one of the condition is executing a single statement:

Bad example:

```
if condition?
  do_something
else
  do_something_else
end
```

This could be written as:

```
return do_something if condition?
do_something_else
```

This will give you less code branching.

---

Also, another recommendation is to call another method with more conditions instead of nesting conditions in one single shot.

Bad example:

```
if condition?
  if condition_two?
    do_something_two
  else
    do_something
  end
else
  do_something_else
end
```

This could be written as:

```
if condition?
  call_another_method 
else
  do_something_else
end

def call_another_method
  if condition_two?
    do_something_two
  else
    do_something
  end
end
```

---

An example from your code could be:

```
if rain_fall_type == 'All'
  all
else
  if year == 'All'
    if rain_fall_type == "None"
      where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id')
    else
      # all
        where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order('id')
    end
  else
    if rain_fall_type == "All"
      order("#{year} ")

    elsif rain_fall_type == "None"
      where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id')
      else
      where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order("#{year} ")
      end
  end
end
```

That could be converted to:

```
return all if rain_fall_type == 'All'
if year == 'All'
  return where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id') if rain_fall_type == "None"
  where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order('id')
else
  return order("#{year} ") if rain_fall_type == "All"
  return where('Sector = ? OR Sector = ? OR Sector = ?', "Primary", 'Secondary', 'Tertiary').order('id') if rain_fall_type == "None"
  where(Sector: rain_fall_type).order("#{year} ")
end
```

I hope this could help :)

**NOTE:** This is to answer the original question of `How to simplify big conditions?`. But the original post is not following Rails/Ruby way of doing search and filters and not making a good use of scopes.

Comment: Or observe that `Sector = ? or Sector = ?` in SQL is equivalent to `Sector in (?, ?)` and that `where(Sector: some_array)` becomes `"Sector" in (...)`. So you can replace some guard conditions with assignments to a `sectors` variable (which may be an array of sectors or just a single sector) and say `where(Sector: sectors)`. This also takes care of possible case sensitivity issues with the `Sector` column name.

Comment: That's true :) I did not pay that much attention to the code logic. I only thought about the most known general practices to simplify nested conditions logic. Good catch 

Comment: This is a bad "answer" to me because it is just more of the same. See my answer below for a truly "Ruby/Rails" way of solving this.

Comment: I like your answer to guide the OP on better practices for Ruby/Rails :) but I read the question as: "How to simplify big conditions?" and that was my answer for this specific question not paying attention to code logic and rails things! I tried to make my answer as generic as possible to help the OP and anyone else who will visit this question in the future searching for "How to simplify big conditions" ..

Comment: @muistooshort could you please edit my answer with your observation? I'll accept your edit after reviewing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TarekN.Elsamni See my answer below on using scopes. This answer here does not do anything to simplify your code. Its must refactoring into slightly less conditionals. If you see my answer I show you how to refactor the code the "Rails Way" to get rid of ALL conditionals.

Comment: I like it :) I'd personally do that the same as you did in my rails project. but I had different POV when I looked into it. I focused more on killing conditions in general and did not think at all about Ruby/Rails. Your answer is more elegant but I wanted to provide a stack/technology agnostic answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the best explanation of how you should set this up.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # custom_scope_1
  scope :status, -> (status) { where status: status }
  # custom_scope_2
  scope :location, -> (location_id) { where location_id: location_id }
  # custom_scope_3
  scope :search, -> (name) { where("name like ?", "#{name}%")}
end

def index
   @products = Product.where(nil) # creates an anonymous scope
   @products = @products.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
   @products = @products.location(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
   @products = @products.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
end
```

This can be cleaned up further by...

```
def index
  @products = Product.where(nil)
  filtering_params(params).each do |key, value|
    @products = @products.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
  end
end

private

# A list of the param names that can be used for filtering the Products
def filtering_params(params)
  params.slice(:status, :location, :search)
end
```

This method uses ruby meta-programming to loop through parameters and dynamically call predefined [scopes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) on a model

You can move this code into a module and include it into any model that supports filtering

`app/models/concerns/filterable.rb`

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```

`app/models/product.rb`

```
class Product
  include Filterable
  ...
end
```

`app/controllers/product_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @products = Product.filter(params.slice(:status, :location, :search))
end
```

You now have filtering and searching of your models with one line in the controller and one line in the model

Comment: moving the selections to `scopes` like in this answer is the way to go 